# Responding to new_session_created messages in the telegram.org API

Tags: python, telegram

In my telegram client I go through the seemingly typical process of creating a valid session:

1. Generate a random session_id
2. Create an auth key
3. Call `initConnection` with `getNearestDc`
4. Switch to the nearest DC, which involves a new random session_id and
   auth_key
5. Attempt a `sendCode` command, which results in another switch to the
   correct DC

At various points in this process I receive `MessageContainers` from the server indicating status and `MsgAcks`, etc. This is expected and I am now decoding them properly. Some of these messages are of type `new_session_created` and look like this:

```
{'msg': {u'new_session_created': {u'first_msg_id': 6327252208304908288L, u'unique_id': -4911750325772918873L, u'server_salt': 6799011375684265530L}}, 'seqno': 1, 'msg_id': 6327252210221112321L}
```

My current server_salt is different than that in this message. Do I need to switch to using the new salt? What about unique_id, is that my new session_id or do I just ignore these messages?

After sorting all this out, what part of the session do I need to save for the next time the client starts up? The session_id, auth_key, auth_key_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save and re-use this new salt you just received for your next requests in this session.

To do a subsequest login all you need is the `session_id`, `recent_salt` and the `auth_key`.

`Auth_key_id` is computed from the `auth_key` so you may, or may not choose to store it

Comment: When doing a subsequent login do I connect to the last DC or to the default, which is usually 2? If I connect to the default the auth_key will be invalid for that DC, right?

Comment: no. The idea is this you connect to the nearest DC which you had determined from your initial connection

Comment: You start off by creating your auth_key in dc 2, then run initconnection in that DC, while asking for your nearestDC. If your nearest DC is 2, that fine if it is different, then your best bet would be to create a new auth_in the new DC, and complete your Authorization in that DC. Store that DC as your main_DC and use it subsequently with your saved salt, session, and auth_key/auth_key_id that all correspond to that DC.

Comment: Once I store the dc, auth_key, salt, etc and exit the client, then startup again, do I need to do initConnection again?

Comment: Also, do I need to reset the message sequence number or start with the one from the last session?

Comment: I always do an initConnection on start up

Comment: If you create a new session, you need to start from seq_no =0, otherwise start from previous seq_no. I just find it more convenient to always start of afresh with session and seq_no